# Configuring WebSphere SIB Components in Jetty for Application Use

Tags: java, queue, jms, websphere, jetty

I want to use remote messaging from my Spring JMS application running on Jetty to place messages onto queues that are configured in a Service Integration Bus on WebSphere 8.5.  I have a working example of my jetty-env.xml using ActiveMQ.

```
<New id="cf" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
    <Arg>jms/connectionFactory</Arg>
    <Arg>
        <New class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
            <Arg>tcp://localhost:61616</Arg>
        </New>
     </Arg>
</New>
```

I have the port for the SIB_ENDPOINT in WebSphere, and I think remoting will use the IIOP protocol:

```
<New id="cf" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
    <Arg>jms/connectionFactory</Arg>
    <Arg>
        <New class="com.ibm.ws.sib.api.jms.impl.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl">
            <Arg>iiop://localhost:7280</Arg>
        </New>
    </Arg>
</New>
```

Trying this, however, yields an IllegalStateException as apparently this class does not contain a constructor.  What am I doing wrong?  How can I configure the appropriate broker in my Spring app on Jetty to access a SIB on a local WAS85 instance?